# Get OpenGL (WGL) context from QOpenGLContext

Tags: opengl, qt5, qtquick2, wgl

I'm trying to get the OpenGL context (HGLRC) from the QQuickView window.
I need to pass it to a non-Qt library. I can get a QOpenGLContext easily enough:

```
m_qtContext = QOpenGLContext::currentContext();
```

How do you obtain the OpenGL context from the Qt class? (QOpenGLContext)

Answer (score 3):

There's not exactly a public API for this, as far as I know. Note that Qt 5 removed most of the native handles from the APIs. This should do the trick:

```
QPlatformNativeInterface *iface = QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface();
HGLRC ctx = (HGLRC)iface->nativeResourceForContext("renderingContext", context);
```

(not sure about the last cast, but that looks correct [according to the relevant source](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/stable/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowsintegration.cpp#L208)).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current OpenGL context from WGL in ***any*** framework if you call `wglGetCurrentContext (...)` while your thread has the context bound. Keep in mind that frameworks will usually change the current context whenever they invoke a window's draw callback / event handler, and may even set it to `NULL` after completing the callback.

WGL has a strict one-to-one mapping for contexts and threads, so in a single-threaded application that renders to multiple windows you will probably have to call this function in a window's draw callback / event handler to get the proper handle.

In simplest terms, any time you have a valid context in which to issue GL commands under Win32, you can get a handle to *that particular* context by calling `wglGetCurrentContext (...)`.

If your framework has a portable way of acquiring a native handle, then by all means use it. But that is definitely not your only option on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: A great help. I wondered about it but didn't know OpenGl well enough to know if it would work

Comment: "WGL has a strict one-to-one mapping for contexts and threads" that's actually true in all GL implementations. The only problem is that the current context might not be your `QOpenGLContext`, that's why I didn't suggest this way...

Comment: @peppe: Indeed, that is why I mentioned having to do this from the window's draw event handler. I mentioned WGL by name because this question is about WGL, it is definitely true that all existing window system implementations have this issue.

Comment: This seems less version dependent than peppe's solution. If I can ensure I call it in the correct event. Perhaps QQuickItem::updatePaintNode(). I'll keep after it. Thank you again